# What is the best way to detail your car inside?

Tags: cleaning, interior

I bought a used car and its seat, doors, dashboard all needs some good cleaning job. I am thinking to shampoo the seats and side doors and then vacuuming it. But I don't know what shampoo to use and how to do it?  I did clean mildew on gear using Windex. It did pretty good job. Need help cleaning the clothe seats and side doors. Do I soak the seat for long, how much water do I use? I have to take the car to outside vacuum for drying the seats.

Comment: If you want to get dust and dirt out of hard to reach places (e.g. a gear shifter), you may want to use a toothbrush.

Answer (score 3):

For cleaning carpets many of the high-end professional detailers avoid using shampoos since it's nearly impossible to rinse out completely and the residue will attract dirt in the future.  Instead they use a steam cleaner.  Here is a video demonstration: http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=7440721179397618761&hl=en

Unfortunately these steam machines are pretty expensive and I've never found a place that will rent one.  So if you do want to go the more traditional route, I'd recommend the Meguiar's carpet cleaning product: http://www.meguiarsdirect.com/product_detail.asp?T1=MEG+D10219.  Just follow the instructions on the can.